# Min.io with AWS SDK 2 for Java refuses to work properly

Tags: aws-sdk, minio

I am trying to work with min.io with AWS SDK 2, after battling it for a few days, I have managed to reach a dead end, I upload the files successfully but still get a client error

AWS CLI works just fine.

```
aws s3 cp --profile minio --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:9000 helloworld.txt s3://abc/helloworld.txt
upload: ./helloworld.txt to s3://abc/helloworld.txt
```

**Also when working with local-stack, everything works fine**

The Java SDK configuration:

```
    private fun buildCustomS3AsyncClient() : S3AsyncClient {
    val customEndpoint : String = env.getRequiredProperty(S3EndpointPropertyName)
    val customEndpointPort : String = env.getRequiredProperty(S3Port)
    //val region: Region = Region.of(env.getRequiredProperty(S3RegionPropertyName))
    val region: Region = Region.US_EAST_1
    val asyncClientBuilder = S3AsyncClient.builder()
    asyncClientBuilder.region(region)
    asyncClientBuilder.endpointOverride(URI.create("http://${customEndpoint}:${customEndpointPort}"))
    val staticCredentialsProvider: StaticCredentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
            AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
                    "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY")
    )
    val confBuilder = software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Configuration
            .builder()
            .pathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .build()
    asyncClientBuilder.serviceConfiguration(confBuilder)
    asyncClientBuilder.credentialsProvider(staticCredentialsProvider)
    return asyncClientBuilder.build()
}
```

and the upload code:

```
    fun uploadToS3(file: File, bucket: String, key: String) : Mono<PutObjectResponse> {
    val putObjectRequest: PutObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build()
    logger.info(putObjectRequest.toString())
    val asyncRequestBody: AsyncRequestBody = AsyncRequestBody.fromFile(file)
    return Mono.fromFuture(s3AsyncClient.putObject(putObjectRequest, asyncRequestBody))
}
```

Stack trace:

```
[sdk-async-response-0-1] ERROR [] [--] o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler - [80ebb08c]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/s3" 
    software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: null
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.*.kotlinplayground.controllers.ReactiveUploadController#uploadHandler(Flux) [DispatcherHandler]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/s3" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
    Stack trace:
            at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97)
            at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.ThrowableUtils.asSdkException(ThrowableUtils.java:98)
            at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryExecutor.retryIfNeeded(AsyncRetryableStage.java:123)
            at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AsyncRetryableStage.java:105)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
            at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$executeHttpRequest$1(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:137)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid base 16 character: '-'
        at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.internal.Base16Codec.pos(Base16Codec.java:80)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.internal.Base16Codec.decode(Base16Codec.java:66)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.internal.Base16Lower.decode(Base16Lower.java:65)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.checksums.ChecksumsEnabledValidator.validatePutObjectChecksum(ChecksumsEnabledValidator.java:131)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.AsyncChecksumValidationInterceptor.afterUnmarshalling(AsyncChecksumValidationInterceptor.java:86)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain.lambda$afterUnmarshalling$9(ExecutionInterceptorChain.java:152)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain.reverseForEach(ExecutionInterceptorChain.java:210)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain.afterUnmarshalling(ExecutionInterceptorChain.java:152)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseClientHandler.runAfterUnmarshallingInterceptors(BaseClientHandler.java:138)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$interceptorCalling$2(BaseClientHandler.java:151)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.handle(AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.java:40)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.handle(AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.java:28)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.AsyncResponseHandler.lambda$prepare$0(AsyncResponseHandler.java:88)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1072)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.AsyncResponseHandler$BaosSubscriber.onComplete(AsyncResponseHandler.java:129)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler$FullResponseContentPublisher$1.request(ResponseHandler.java:358)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.AsyncResponseHandler$BaosSubscriber.onSubscribe(AsyncResponseHandler.java:108)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler$FullResponseContentPublisher.subscribe(ResponseHandler.java:349)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.AsyncResponseHandler.onStream(AsyncResponseHandler.java:71)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.AsyncAfterTransmissionInterceptorCallingResponseHandler.onStream(AsyncAfterTransmissionInterceptorCallingResponseHandler.java:86)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage$ResponseHandler.onStream(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:253)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler.channelRead0(ResponseHandler.java:107)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler.channelRead0(ResponseHandler.java:66)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:129)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:148)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.LastHttpContentHandler.channelRead(LastHttpContentHandler.java:43)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:326)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:300)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have looked deeper into it, and it seems that the AWS SDK decodes the ETag returned in the response using "Base16Lower", the ETag returned by min.io contains the '-' character (for example "afb0b3566f2a2a57d59a1487c413eb30-1"), which is unacceptable by the decoder, that is why the upload is successful, but parsing the response fails.

awssdk:s3:2.5.29

I was able to bypass the issue by disabling the checksum validation in the client configuration

```
val confBuilder = software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Configuration.builder().pathStyleAccessEnabled(true).checksumValidationEnabled(false).build()
```